# Internal /bin/cp command failed. xCode compiler error

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, xcode6, nsarchiving

I'm working in Xcode trying to build a simple calendar app.  As I tried to build and run I get this error

```
/Users/Zach/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/COnonts/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/
usr/bin/bitcode_strip: internal /bin/cp command failed.
```

Task Failed with exit 1 signal 0 {

All I know is that it gives me the error when this line is typed... It goes away when I comment it out.

```
            let ce = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: eventObject as Data) as! CalenderEvent
```

**UPDATE:**
I just tried to recompile and was given a new error.

```
"libswiftCore.dylib" couldn't be copied to "(A Document Being Saved BY Xcode)".
```

It appears like something is wrong with the swift std library.  It randomly switches between the two errors.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libraries? What is `CalenderEvent` ?

Comment: `CalenderEvent` is a variable defined earlier @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift

Comment: `let ce = CalenderEvent(withTitle: newEvent, andDateString: defaultsKey)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get this same error when I run low on disk space.  Try moving the project to a different location, with more space, clean the project, and re-build.